# Mask R-CNN not working properly on its own examples

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, image-segmentation

I spent some time already to figure out how to get Mask R-CNN working properly.
I cloned the original [Matterport implementation](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN) and a fork of it which has been modified to use [TF 2](https://github.com/leekunhee/Mask_RCNN/tree/tensorflow2.0).

The Matterport implementation seems to be somehow outdated with respect to the dependencies, and I could not make it work. I saw that some people could make it work using different versions of the required libraries or some code changes here and there... I thought I continue with the TF2 compatible version. There is a code change needed as well to make it work with the examples which have been provided with [Mask R-CNN](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/2243). I hope that this is sufficient and that I did not miss something else.

E.g. I ran the `train_shapes.ipynb` in `samples` folder. The generated shapes are trained on top of pretrained COCO weights. So far so good.
The notebook generates a sample image with shapes, and processes it. this is the result:

[image: generated sample image]
[image: visualization of detected shapes]

What can be the reason that so many shapes are detected which are not in the source image?

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue. It is because `model.detect` does not work for TensorFlow 2.6 and above. When I downgraded to TensorFlow 2.4, everything worked. Check out this thread: https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/2670

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ended up using the Mask-RCNN implementation from torchvision.

Answer (score 0):

Just as previously stated, dropping below Tesorflow 2.6 helped me, but you will run into many other dependency problems. I have made my own version of the `requirements.txt` file and it should help you resolve most of them.

```
numpy==1.19.*
scipy<1.3.0
Pillow
cython
matplotlib
scikit-image
tensorflow==2.5.*
keras>=2.0.8
opencv-python
h5py==3.1.0
imgaug
IPython[all]
```

Run `pip install -r requirements.txt` and it should fix your issue.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I ended up using the Mask-RCNN implementation from torchvision.